# Unable to edit .bash_profile file on mac

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

Unable to edit `~/.bash_profile` file on my mac. I did some changes in this file and rebooted. From then nothing is working on my command line:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of a screenshot please use copy/paste to show Terminal output. This makes it accessible to people with screen readers and to the search function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `/usr/bin/vim ~/.bash_profile` and fix whatever is wrong in the assignment to `PATH`.